# apply colspan on specific column on a dynamic table using mat-table

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-material-table

I have `mat-table` in which columns get created dynamically
I want to add a expand column functionality using `[attr.colspan]`
if a click event is detected on a column header the attr gets applied on that specific column

inserting it in the HTML template applies the change to the first column

```
 <ng-container
matColumnDef="{{ column }}"
*ngFor="let column of displayedColumns">
<th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef (click)="headerEvent(column)">{{ column }}</th>
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"
[attr.colspan]="1"
>{{ element[column] }}</td>
</ng-container>
```

How can I apply the `[attr.colspan]` dynamically ?

[stack blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-table-hide-columns-pure-obserabl-hzbrun?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use any expresion, e.g.

```
<th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef (click)="headerEvent(column)">
  {{ column }}
</th>
<ng-container mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
  <td
    *ngIf="!element.colspan || column != 'name'"
    [attr.colspan]="column == 'position'?element.colspan:null"
  >
    {{ element[column] }}
  </td>
</ng-container>
```

And you have data some like

```
 [
  {position: 1, name: 'Hydrogen', weight: 1.0079, symbol: 'H'},
  {position: 2, name: 'Helium', weight: 4.0026, symbol: 'He',colspan:2}
 ]
```

See your [forked stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-table-hide-columns-pure-obserabl-st17be?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

See that you "remove" the next td when you make a colspan